# Wordpass В url появляется выражение %20 и после перегрузки сайт не открывается

Tags: php

Сайт в wordpass после перехода в записях в URL появлятся выражение %20 и сайт не открывается как исправить

Answer (score 1):

При [url encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP#midcontentadcontainer) пробел заменяется на "%20". В данном случае необходимо проверить на наличие пробела при редиректе и убрать его. Тогда все заработает!